# Intent extras missing on rooted devices

Tags: android

I use intent extras to pass parameters to my activity when starting it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("someKey", "someValue");
startActivity(intent);
```

This works perfectly fine and I can get the extras from the bundle in MyActivity's onCreate

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("someKey");
```

value was never null when I tested it and I am sure that there is no other part in my code that would create an intent for MyActivity.

The problem is that I often get crash reports (through Crashlytics), telling me that getting the extra returned null. This only seems to happen  on rooted devices, so I suspect that there is some other app on those devices that causes this problem. I was not able to reproduce this issue on my own rooted devices.

Did anyone else run into this problem or would know of a root-app that could cause this? Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

After more detailed analysis I noticed that these crash reports only come from the following two devices: *Samsung Galaxy Nexus* and *Motorola Nexus 6*
So it is most likely a problem related to these devices and not the fact that they report as rooted.

Comment: Root users being a cause of this are extremely *unlikely*. It could be a developer attempting to start your App themselves. Can you tell if it is coming from a multitude of devices or perhaps from very few devices?

Comment: I get these crash reports from many different users, devices and Android versions. The only thing they share is that their devices are rooted.

Comment: I had a thought. What happens if you open your App so that `MyActivity` is showing. Then use the home button, do something else (use a different App) for several minutes, then use the App switcher and go back to your App with it. It *could* be that users are coming back to your App after your Activity is removed from memory and Android tries to recreate it (but without your provided intents).

Comment: have You ever tried to get the extras with getStringExtra() ? I had similar problems in the past and intent.getStringExtra() has worked.....I read something about that this must be a kind of bug in the system....not sure, but try it.....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I didn't do this with getStringExtra(), but I in a different part of my app I use getBundleExtra(), which has the same problem.

Comment: @Knossos Yeah, I suspect that it's related to the activity getting recreated. But shouldn't the original intent be used for this? I mean, the intent is useless if important extras are missing.
I tried this on my devices by using a memory filler app to make sure that my app was fully destroyed and recreated, but I didn't get the crash and my extras were there in the recreated activity.

Comment: I'm having the same problem -- a Motorola Nexus 6 on Android 7.1.1 is reporting crashes but I don't have that device to reproduce it with.  I'm attempting a workaround/hack -- saving the extras in `onSaveInstanceState` and restoring them in `onCreate`.